# Can a monstruous character that failed the 24h negative level save lose a monster HD?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, undead, character-levels

Ming the Minotaur Gladiator took it really bad during the *"undead night fight"* event at the Westgate arena.

He got some negative levels while fighting some vampires. Eeek.

Now 24h later, he made all his saves, except one. He is [going to lose a level](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#energyDrainAndNegativeLevels)....

Can he lose one of his monster HD (instead of a level of fighter, for example)?

Comment: I'll let the community decide if this question is a duplicate of [this question.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/107844/8610)

Comment: @HeyICanChan look **"Community♦ "** has voted for dupe... `:)` .... It worked, somehow.

Comment: That's hilarious. Anyway, you might also be interested in [this question.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/105658/8610)